# Generic Factorial function in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a generic function to calculate factorial in C# ... like:

```
 static T Factorial<T>(T n)
        {
            if (n <= 1)
                return 1;

            return Factorial<T>(n - 1);
        }
```

but obviously having restriction that we can't perform operations on type '`T`'. any alternative?

Comment: as soon as it works it will always return 1 ^^

Comment: why are you using generics? How can you calculate factorial on something that's not a number? I don't know C# so well, but wouldn't it be better for T to be a number? Is there a number interface or class that T can extend/implement?

Comment: @charma - I agree that it's usefulness is limited... but I'm assuming he wants to have the factorial be for multiple integer types... short, int, long and even floating point types. Though I think in this case, just writing an int version and casting after the call is sufficient.

Comment: what would the factorial of "Hello World" be?

Comment: @Nick in java there is a Number abstract class which all number types inherit from. If there is something similar in c#, he could extend it, and then only number types will be accepted

Comment: @chama - C# doesn't have such a construct. That's why I referenced the Generic Operators library in my answer.

Comment: @Stan: In the same vein: how do I sort non-comparable objects? Does this mean I can’t provide a generic `Sort` method?

Comment: @mqpasta: Don’t be unduly worried by the negative reactions. This is actually a very good question but C# just doesn’t address this particular use-case of generics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 public T Factorial<T>(T a, T b, Multiply<T> delegateMutliply, Difference<T> diffDelegate, BaseCondition<T> baseDelegate)
    {
        if (!baseDelegate(a, b))
            return b;

        return delegateMutliply(a, Factorial<T>(diffDelegate(a), b, delegateMutliply, diffDelegate, baseDelegate));
    }
```

int y = p.Factorial(3, 1, (a, b) => a * b, (a) => --a, (a, b) => (a <= b) ? false : true);

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that generics don't support operators because they are static methods, and not part of an interface.  However, you could probably use [Generic Operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html), which is available in the [Miscellaneous Utility Library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

You would need to add a delegate parameter which performs the multiplication. Something like this

```
delegate T Multiply<T>(T a, T b);
```

So then your function would be defined like this:

```
static T Factorial<T>(T n, Multiply func)
{
    ... your code here
}
```

So when your factorial function is called, the caller would pass in the multiplication function:

```
int x = Factorial<int>(5, (a,b) => a * b);
```

Comment: FYI You might need additional delegate functions / values to be passed in to handle your "1" case.

Comment: This indeed gets the job done, but then it's kind of stretching the definition of "Factorial." It might as well be called `DoRecursiveOperation`. After all, I could legally call `Factorial<int>(5, (a,b) => b - a)` and what I'd be getting would not be the result of a factorial at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this. I have seen some solutions that work around the problem, but they are fairly complicated. That said, if you really want to do this here are a few ideas:

1. If you can use .Net 4, you can cast `n` to `dynamic` and then perform the addition. You lose safety, of course - you could get an exception at runtime
2. You could always manually check the type from within your factorial function: If `n` is a short, cast to short, if `n` is a double, cast to double... etc. That is complicated and defeats part of the value of generics, but the outside API at least looks simple.

Answer (score 1):

When's the last time you took the factorial of a string, or a character?
Why do you ever need a factorial of type T????

Besides this has been said numerous (prolly 1 million times now).
When you need to use a generic you need to tell the compiler the type.

For instance what if I had a generic stack class?
C# needs to know the elements type when I create my stack.

Otherwise it makes no sense for:

```
Stack<T> s = new Stack<T>();
s.Push(????); //how do I add items to the stack if we don't know what T is?
```

Instead you need to specify:

```
Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
s.Push(5);
s.Push(7);
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense to restrict a generic type parameter `T` to a class of types, e.g. `IComparable` types, or merely numerical types. .NET unfortunately doesn’t offer such an interface that is implemented by all built-in numerical types but in theory at least, this is useful. The question after factorials for strings is an *argumentum ad absurdum* and thus a straw-man fallacy.

Comment: @Konrad - The concept makes sense but for this particular question it doesn't.

Comment: @JonH: In Haskell, I might well be tempted to write two versions, one using `Int` for performance, and one using `Integer` (a kind of bignum) to allow very large numbers. Also, I wouldn’t put too much emphasis on the particular example the OP chose, since the question in general crops up in various places.

Comment: @Konrad, if you are writing two versions why cant you cast ?

Comment: I **don’t** actually want to write two versions. I want to write *one* generic piece of code without catering to special cases.

Comment: @Konrad you dont have to hence the cast.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specifically addressing your question about making the method generic, but your method as it stands will never return anything other than 1.

Supposing you were only working with integers, it should look like this:

```
static int Factorial(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;

    // note the multiplication in this step
    return n * Factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Super old question but I'd like to add my 2 cents.

Factorial functions require `f* = i`

A quick function for the example above is:

```
    class FindFactorial
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your number: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

        int factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(factorial);
    }
}
```